# using Direct package file upload method in magento theme done not uploaded

Tags: php, magento, file-upload

I cannot upload theme in Magento using Direct package file upload method.
The zip file is 90MB. Have already increase size in `php.ini` file 
as mention below

```
upload_max_filesize = 250M
post_max_size = 250M
```

Error :

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 94773597 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
No file was uploaded
```

Comment: After theses changes did you restart the server?

Comment: thanks, yes i restart xampp server now it gives following error

SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2014-11-29') AS DiffDate

Comment: Where are you developing your site localhost or some hosted server? Please mention the error in detail and when it is occurring?